# Java Set Stipulation

Tags: java, set

Java docs says the following about Set interface, can someone please help me understand how these additional stipulations are forced? I mean you cannot throw an extra exception that is not thrown by super interface (in this case Collection).

> The Set interface places additional
>   stipulations, beyond those inherited
>   from the Collection interface, on the
>   contracts of all constructors and on
>   the contracts of the add, equals and
>   hashCode methods.

Thanks

-Abidi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stipulations are not forced, they are just added to the contract.

Luckily the contracts of the methods in `Collection` (and `Object`) are loose enough that an implementation can implement both the contract from `Collection`, `Object` and `Set` without violating any of these.

For example, the `add` method does not throw Exceptions when trying to add an object which is already in it, it just returns `false` (instead of `true`). This is already allowed by `Collection.add`:

> Ensures that this collection contains the specified element (optional operation). Returns true if this collection changed as a result of the call. (Returns false if this collection does not permit duplicates and already contains the specified element.)

Answer (score 3):

These are contractual stipulations.

It means that all `Set`s are *expected* to obey these rules.
They aren't enforced.